# Dropdown menus become black in the middle of a session

Tags: menu, version-11.2

For some reason, the dropdown menus on my version of Mathematica 11.2.0.0 sometimes become black in the middle of a session so that I can no longer see any of the text. I am using a MacBook Pro from 2015. An screenshot of the problem is included at the bottom.

Does anyone know why this is happening? There's no way for me to cause the menu to go back to being the normal colour without restarting the program.

[image]

Comment: I saw this in 11.2, see it no longer in 11.3. I'd upgrade.

Comment: Same, I had it on MMA 11.1 and 11.2, problem solved on 11.3.

Comment: Thanks - I'll upgrade to 11.3.

Comment: I believe this has been asked before. If I remember correctly I thought it had to do with the FE running using too much memory and then effectively failing. Happened for me if I rasterized and displayed a lot of large images and things.